# Question about biquadratic extension over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

> Let $m$ be a negative integer, and suppose that $K$ is a quartic extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ contains $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$ as a subfield.

In this situation, I have two questions:

Q1) Is the existence of such an quartic extension $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ implies the positive integer $n:=-m$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Q2) If the first question is true, I wonder if $K$ is necessarily a biquadratic extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n},i)$, and thus, $K$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\textrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})\cong\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

I've been thinking a lot of time, but I'm not sure about my questions.

A little advice would help me a lot! Thank you.

Comment: If you don’t add conditions on the quartic extension you can’t say much. But for instance you can prove the quartic extension can’t be cyclic

Comment: I don't know from which context this question comes, but in any case this is some comment for (1). Consider $\mathbf{Q}\subset\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-1})\subset \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-1},\sqrt{2})$. This is a biquadratic extension since $\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{-2}\not\in\mathbf{Q}$. However, $1$ is a square in $\mathbf{Q}$.. You need to have more information about $\mathbf{Q}\subset K$ to say something.

Comment: What do you mean by a quartic extension K of Q ? Simply that K is an extension of degree 4 ?  A galois extension of degree 4 ?

Comment: @TokenToucan Thank you for comments

Comment: @rae306 Thank you for comments. I found what I was thinking wrong.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo It was the former. But I found what I was thinking wrong.